# How to declare Global Variables in Excel VBA to be visible across the Workbook

Tags: excel, module, global-variables, public, vba

I have a question about global scope and have abstracted the problem into a simple example:

In an Excel Workbook:
In **Sheet1** I have two(2) buttons.
The first is labeled **SetMe** and is linked to a subroutine in **Sheet1's module**:
**Sheet1 code:**

```
Option Explicit
Sub setMe()
    Global1 = "Hello"
End Sub
```

The second is labeled **ShowMe** and is linked to a subroutine in **ThisWorkbook's module**:
**ThisWorkbook code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Global1 As String
Debug.Print("Hello")
Sub showMe()
    Debug.Print (Global1)
End Sub
```

Clicking on **SetMe** produces a compiler `error: variable not defined`.
When I create a separate module and move the declaration of **Global1** into it everything works.

**So my question is:**
Everything I have read says that Global variables, declared at the top of a module, outside of any code should be visible to all modules in the project.  Clearly this is not the case.
Unless my understanding of **Module** is not correct.
The objects `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `ThisWorkbook`,... that come with a workbook: are these not modules capable of declaring variables at global scope?

Or is the only place one can declare a global, in a separate module of type **Modules**.

Comment: I believe UserForms' Code falls into the category type Module even though it's not really listed as such.  Is that correct?

Comment: @sancho.s I deleted it to avoid confusion :) I missed that Pearson's Link and misinterpreted one line in the MSDN link I posted. Learned something new today :)

Comment: Did you find any useful answers here? It is always good to give feedback, so other SO users can see.

Answer (score 26):

Your question is:
*are these not modules capable of declaring variables at global scope?*

**Answer: YES, they are "capable"**

The only point is that references to global variables in `ThisWorkbook` or a Sheet module have to be fully qualified (i.e., referred to as `ThisWorkbook.Global1`, e.g.)
References to global variables in a standard module have to be fully qualified only in case of ambiguity (e.g., if there is more than one standard module defining a variable with name `Global1`, and you mean to use it in a third module).

For instance, place in `Sheet1` code

```
Public glob_sh1 As String

Sub test_sh1()
    Debug.Print (glob_mod)
    Debug.Print (ThisWorkbook.glob_this)
    Debug.Print (Sheet1.glob_sh1)
End Sub
```

place in `ThisWorkbook` code

```
Public glob_this As String

Sub test_this()
    Debug.Print (glob_mod)
    Debug.Print (ThisWorkbook.glob_this)
    Debug.Print (Sheet1.glob_sh1)
End Sub
```

and in a Standard Module code

```
Public glob_mod As String

Sub test_mod()
    glob_mod = "glob_mod"
    ThisWorkbook.glob_this = "glob_this"
    Sheet1.glob_sh1 = "glob_sh1"
    Debug.Print (glob_mod)
    Debug.Print (ThisWorkbook.glob_this)
    Debug.Print (Sheet1.glob_sh1)
End Sub
```

All three subs work fine.

PS1: This answer is based essentially on info from [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/codemods.htm). It is much worth reading (from the great Chip Pearson).

PS2: Your line `Debug.Print ("Hello")` will give you the compile error `Invalid outside procedure`.

PS3: You could (partly) check your code with *Debug -> Compile VBAProject* in the VB editor. All compile errors will pop.

PS4: Check also [Put Excel-VBA code in module or sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255478/put-excel-vba-code-in-module-or-sheet).

PS5: You might be not able to declare a global variable in, say, `Sheet1`, and use it in code from other workbook (reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241%28v=office.15%29.aspx#sectionSection0; I did not test this point, so this issue is yet to be confirmed as such). But you do not mean to do that in your example, anyway.

PS6: There are several cases that lead to ambiguity in case of not fully qualifying global variables. You may tinker a little to find them. They are compile errors.

Comment: I misinterpreted one line in the link I posted. Learned something new today :). Definitely +1. If I could vote more than once, I would've done so.

Comment: This was driving me mad - adding `Public thing as New Thing` to a module instead of to ThisWorkbook solved all of the "424" error issues when trying to access `thing.something()`

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following to learn/test the concept:

1. Open new Excel Workbook and in Excel VBA editor right-click on Modules->Insert->Module
2. In newly added Module1 add the declaration; `Public Global1 As String`
3. in Worksheet VBA Module Sheet1(Sheet1) put the code snippet:

> ```
> Sub setMe()
>       Global1 = "Hello"
> End Sub
> ```

4. in Worksheet VBA Module Sheet2(Sheet2) put the code snippet:

> ```
> Sub showMe()
>     Debug.Print (Global1)
> End Sub
> ```

5. Run in sequence Sub `setMe()` and then Sub `showMe()` to test the global visibility/accessibility of the var `Global1`

Hope this will help.

Comment: Simple, thx, works for me. I've named one module "Globals" and use it for nothing else but defining global variables - no subs or functions or any code in there, just globals defined

Comment: You are welcome! Glad it works for you. Please mark the answer accepted if you are satisfied with the solution. Best regards,