# Excel VBA immediate window produces a blank line while testing my function, but works normally while testing built-in functions

Tags: excel, vba

Here is what happened.
I am just a beginner, and i was watching a tutorial video today. At 2:58, the guy in the video just tested the function and it returned a value.

I did the exact same thing as following:

```
Function customDate() As String  
    customDate = Format(Date, "dddd dd mmmm yyyy")
End Function
```

And test this in the immediate window with the following command:

```
?customDate
```

the immediate window produced a blank line.

However, if i do this with a built-in function such as:

```
?Date
```

it will work and give me a value.

My question is: how do I test my own function in that window.

Comment: BTW, when I step into this function or use this in another macro, it actually returns the value to other macros. it's just I cannot see the print result of my own function in the immediate window

Comment: And apparently, my excel does not recognize my own function coz I cannot find my functions while trying to insert my functions in excel

Comment: Seems like problem solved.
This happens if i put my code under the worksheets.
If i copy&paste my code into a new module, everything works fine

Comment: User Defined Functions (**UDF**) that are in a normal module can only be called if it's loaded, either by AddIn, StartUp files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This happens if i put my code under the worksheets. If i copy&paste my code into a new module, everything works fine

Yes, the code has to be in the proper place in order to reference it from the immediate window.

Please see these other questions for more information regarding where code belongs.

[Put Excel-VBA code in module or sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255478/put-excel-vba-code-in-module-or-sheet)

[What difference does it make if one runs a VBA code in `Sheets`, in `ThisWorkbook`, and in `Modules`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955461/what-difference-does-it-make-if-one-runs-a-vba-code-in-sheets-in-thisworkboo)