# EXCEL VBA code in the Sheets or in the module

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and was confused on where to put excel VBA code, as we can put it in the module or in the sheet itself, suppose I want to write a code which filters my raw data based on cell value in another sheet and make a chart out of it. Can I write all of this macro in the module or do I need to write the chart making and filtering module separately and call them from the sheet code? Is that compulsory?

Comment: All code goes into the code sheets. Write and view code in the VB Editor.

Comment: @Variatus I meant in the editor , should we write in the modules or in the individual sheets ( by clicking on the sheets)

Comment: The worksheets' code sheets should contain code required by those sheets, especially even procedures. I would have to see your code in order to answer your question. However, I suggest that you try to place the code in standard modules first. If that's the wrong place it won't work as advertised. You can also try the other way around.

Comment: Use a Module when the code is generic, and use the Worksheet when you need to tie it into an Event specific to that Worksheet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255478/put-excel-vba-code-in-module-or-sheet and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955461/what-difference-does-it-make-if-one-runs-a-vba-code-in-sheets-in-thisworkboo  It is a matter of opinion and experience, however, there are some best practices: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices#t=20170801113316024155 And http://www.eusprig.org/best-practice.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put Excel-VBA code in module or sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255478/put-excel-vba-code-in-module-or-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

There is another case where it is advisable to write the code corresponding to the sheet events (Worksheet_SelectionChange, Worksheet_Change, etc.) in a module outside the sheet, and that is when multiple sheets use the same code for their events. In this case it is practical to place said code outside the sheets and make a call to it from the sheet's event procedures, for example:

Inside each sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next

Sheet_Selection Target

End Sub
```

and out in a module:

```
Public Sub Sheet_Selection(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
...
End Sub
```

Note that the procedure within the sheets is private, but the procedure in the module must be public to be accessible throughout the project.