# Calling an excel VBA function in a workbook or sheet in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on the VBA code development on Excel and wanted to ask if we can call a function from a cell.

So for the Excel, we can write functions

- in a sheet
- in the workbook
- in a module

Let assume that I write a function like this:

```
Public Function Area(x As Double, y As Double) As Double
    Area = x * y
End Function
```

Whenever I put the function in a module, I can call that function in a cell using the `=Area(x,y)` and the Area becomes available in Excel's function list. However, when I put the same Area function in a sheet or the workbook, `=Area(x,y)` doesn't work. I have tried `=Sheet1!Area(x,y)` or `=Book1!Area(x,y)`, but all of them returned `#NAME`. I have checked on the net and here but couldn't find a way to use a function in a sheet/workbook in a cell.

Can you please let me know if it is possible or not? And if it is, can you please provide an example of how to call the function from a cell?

Comment: I have checked the provided link which says it is not possible, but on the other two links it is stated that a UDF can be put in a sheet or workbook: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955461/what-difference-does-it-make-if-one-runs-a-vba-code-in-sheets-in-thisworkboo and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255478/put-excel-vba-code-in-module-or-sheet  . Thus I believe putting UDFs in a sheet or workbook is possible but I am still not sure how those functions can be used.

Comment: Not possible for UDFs that are used in a cell... see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955461/what-difference-does-it-make-if-one-runs-a-vba-code-in-sheets-in-thisworkboo#comment17565610_12955737). Hence this is a duplicate and the answer is "it's not possible."